# Best practice if statment

Tags: php

Which is good to use and why?

```
if ($a == 3) {
  //do something
}
```

Or

```
 if (3 == $a) {
      //do something
  }
```

Comment: Id say this isn't a question for code review, as there isn't any code to review !

Comment: This isn't a code review, but it is a interesting question. The last snippet is called Yoda notation. The Symfony Coding Standards require Yoda notation, but PSR, Slevomat and Squiz don't.

Comment: @Stephan and OP: It's considered a bad practice in most other languages. [Relevant Software Engineering answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/162258/148842).

Comment: I agree. One of the few rules in the Symfony Coding Standard I don't agree with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither and both.

The 'both'

`x == $assignedVariable` is a method of defensive programming which is aimed at preventing accidental assignment if someone was to use `$x = 3` by mistake. Whether this offers value is debatable; modern systems exist which catch these mistakes, IDE' can flag this easily and its a bit moot given that someone can accidentally do `$x = 3` just as easily as `3 = $x`. The difference is assignment vs exception.

The 'neither'

You are using a truthy condition(==) which in your example should be changed to a value and type check(===). Truthy checks absolutely still do have a place but within the confines of your example a type check is definitely suitable. Take the following example which should highlight the point.

```
var_dump($a == 3); // true
var_dump($a === 3); // true
var_dump($a == "3"); // true
var_dump($a === "3"); // false
```